# Does BigQuery include intraday tables when I query over all dates up to current date?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Google Analytics 360 data in BigQuery has two intraday tables for the past two days, and permanent partitioned tables for the dates before that. When I run a query on the ga_sessions_ tables for the past 30 days, does this automatically include the two days' data in the ga_sessions_intraday_ tables or do I have to include them specifically?

Edit; here is a query that illustrates this:

`SELECT date, visitId, totals.transactions
FROM`dataset.ga_sessions_2018*
`WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "0401"
  AND CAST(CURRENT_DATE() as STRING)
  ORDER BY date DESC`

The result is that the most recent date is two days ago (ie not including intraday tables.) That's my question answered I guess, thanks anyway.

Comment: What is the query that you are running? There isn't enough information to tell.

Comment: I have included an example query now, sorry. In this case, as BQ cannot find the ga_sessions_20180424 table (as it is still in intraday) it disregards that part of the query? I'm just looking for a way to query across all ga_sessions tables as well as ga_sessions_intraday tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query across whatever tables you want; just write a filter that matches the right suffixes. For example,

```
SELECT date, visitId, totals.transactions, _TABLE_SUFFIX AS suffix
FROM `dataset.ga_sessions_*` WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'[0-9]+')
  BETWEEN "20180401" AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
ORDER BY date DESC
```

I put the suffix in the select list so you can tell which table is matched.

Comment: Thanks Elliott, that is what I was looking for. Cheers,